Solving $a^{\phi(n)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for an unknown $a$ in the context of Euler's Theorem
Let $\phi$ denote Euler's totient function. Then, by Euler's theorem, if gcd$(a,n)=1$, then
$$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}. $$
Consider $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*=G$, the multiplicative group of the ring of integers mod $n$. I'm wondering whether it's true that there exists $a \in G$ such that $a^{\phi(n)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod n$, and $a^{m} \not \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for any $m<\phi(n)/2$. For every example I can think of, it turns out that there is, but I can't prove it in the general case.
If $n$ is prime, then this is easy, as $G \cong C_{n-1}$, which is cyclic of even order.
For example, if we consider $G=(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^*$, note that $\phi(32)=16$, and $3^8=1$, and $3^m \ne 1$ for any $m<8$. This is also true of $5$. It's not, however, true of all primes in $G$, as $7^4=1$. So it's hard to establish a pattern, even in examples.
In the examples I've generated, I've noticed that the smallest prime will have order $\phi(n)/2$, but I can't figure out why this is, and if this pattern holds in general.

See the Carmichael Function.  In particular, for, say, $n=24$, we have $\varphi(24)=8$ but every unit has order $1$ or $2$.
